# How to install network drivers during installation?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I have a server that I'm attempting to install windows onto.
However, the disk is an iscsi target provided by ipxe.

Everything appears to go well until about 3/4 through the install process I get an error about a critical driver missing and the installation is cancelled.

I would say the critical driver would be the network card.  It's an intel nic and the drivers are not on the windows installation CD.

I tried slipstreaming them with RTSevenLite, but after it created the CD it seems it failed to make it bootable.  I've also not been successful in making a bootable USB thumb drive or USB HDD.  I suspect a buggy bios even though I have the latest.

How to install network drivers during installation?

Windows used to provide an optional F6 during install feature but this seems to be missing in Windows Servert 2008.  Perhaps there is a way to do this, or another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get to the screen that lets you select which partition to install Windows on, there is an option to load additional device drivers.

Or you could press `SHIFT+F10` to get a command-line prompt and use [`drvload`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744511%28v=WS.10%29.aspx).

Also, if loading the network drivers doesn't resolve the problem, you could try using [`iscsicli`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/san/archive/2008/07/27/iscsi-initiator-command-line-reference-and-server-core-configuration.aspx) after loading the network drivers to explicitly establish an iSCSI session rather than using ipxe.  I'm not very familiar with this technology, though, so I'm not sure what the recommended approach is.